# Django 2.x - using ModelForm to create a list in a form with unlimited items

Tags: django

I am attempting to create a ModelForm that contains (but is not just) a field where unlimited items can be added. To clarify, the common ToDo list example is almost exactly what I want to do, where users can add an item in an input and it is displayed to the user as added to the ToDo list. In it, the user can add as many items to a list as they want before submitting the form that also contains other fields like a title and description.

I have seen how to do this with custom forms, but I am trying to master ModelForms and keep all the forms on this learning project as ModelForms.

My question is, is this possible with ModelForms? I have thought that perhaps an array can be created, where each added item can be appended to the array, and on the final form submission that array can be stored in the db, but it is above my skill level to actually implement that. Is this the right track, or is there a better way? Thanks for helping me learn!

Comment: You can probably use ModelForms for what you need but it actually depends of the logic you need for your "todo items". What you need is not clear: should users be able to fill as many fields as he want, or choose between values in database ? Exemple of what you've already tried would help

Comment: @May.D In example, if someone wanted to create like a shopping list, where they could title the list, add a description for the list and then add as many items to the list as needed

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to store arrays in databases. Just create a new table for the arrays items. In this case, you have to create a Django model for "ToDo" with a many-to-one relationship with User (or List). For example:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True, blank=False)
    # etc...

class ToDo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then create its forms:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = [...]
        model = User

class ToDoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = [...]
        model = ToDo
```

View:

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
    todo_form = ToDoForm(request.POST)

    if user_form.is_valid() and todo_form.is_valid():

        user = user_form.save()
        todo_form.save()
        todo_form.cleaned_data['user'] = user
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/success')        

if request.method == 'GET':
        context = {
            'user_form': user_form,
            'todo_form': todo_form,
        }

else:
    context = {
        'user_form': UserForm(),
        'todo_form': ToDoForm(),
    }

return TemplateResponse(request, 'your_template.html', context)
```

Template:

```
<form action="your_view" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ user_form.as_p }}
    {{ todo_form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">
</form>
```